# スクロールボタンのスクロールをキャンセルする方法

Tags: javascript

エディタのようなものをつくってまして、例えば以下のようなマウスのホイールボタンの押下で要素を動かすようなイベントを作りたいのですが、スクロールバーが出ているときはスクロールが優先されて、要素がうまく動かせません。
        何か上手い方法はございませんでしょうか。

コードスニペッド:

```js
var a=document.createElement("div")
a.style.width=a.style.height="100px"
a.style.backgroundColor="blue"
a.style.top="500px"
a.innerHTML = "高さ確保用"

var b=document.createElement("div")
b.style.width=b.style.height="100px"
b.style.backgroundColor="red"
b.innerHTML = "中ボタンドラッグで移動"
a.style.position=b.style.position="absolute"
document.body.appendChild(a)
document.body.appendChild(b)

var drag=false
var preX
var preY
b.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
    if(e.button==1){
        drag=true
        preX=e.clientX
        preY=e.clientY
    }
})
window.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
    if(drag){
        b.style.left=(parseInt(b.style.left)||0 )+e.clientX-preX+"px"
        b.style.top=(parseInt(b.style.top ||0))+e.clientY-preY+"px"
        preX=e.clientX
        preY=e.clientY
    }
    
})
window.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>{
    drag=false
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 質問文の状況説明がいまいちわかりません。現在のコードでは、中ボタンによるドラッグ操作で赤いボックスを任意の位置に移動できるようになっています。ただし、スクロールが可能な場合、ドラッグが画面端に到達しても自動でスクロールしないため、その方向にそれ以上ドラッグ移動できません。この認識で正しいでしょうか

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました。自分としてはページがスクロールするのをやめてほしかったのですが、mousedownイベントでe.preventDefault()すればよかったのですね。回答していただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 可能であれば自己回答をして、その回答が承認可能になったらベストアンサーとして承認してください。スタック・オーバーフローでは後で他の方が参考にできる形にする事を推奨されています

Answer (score -1):

mousedown
デフォルトの動作
ドラッグ/ドロップ操作を開始する、テキスト選択を開始する、（サポートされている場合、中ボタンと組み合わせて）スクロール/パンを開始する等。(MDN web docsより)
デフォルトの動作キャンセルにより問題は解決しました。